# what are the different componenets needed to produce and sell an application in C#?

Tags: c#

I need some help with my knowledge of .NET !

ive always created applications using C#(for fun), i also have knowledge in C, however i have some unanswered question and ive been searching for days!

> > once i create my form and my application is running fine, do i need to add a class of any sort to programeName.cs file? and why (i breifly know why but i need to understand exactly why, and when is it a must) ?
> >
> > when im finished with the application design and my previous question is answered; what do i need to do to sell the application? do i just burn a CD with the .exe in it?? :S

i guess my question would be, what are the different componenets needed to produce and sell an application? is it really as simple as just creating a windows application form that works??

Cheers

Comment: Hate to poke a pin in the optimism balloon but if you're still having technical queries like the one you've raised then you are a fair way from being able to produce commercial quality software, not to mention the lack of formatting/spell-checking in your question would conflict with the attention to detail and care present in successful applications and businesses. Having said that I'm glad to see your passion and excitement and wish you well on your software development path.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really about two things:

1. Technical completion
2. Distribution

You don't need to do anything special, short of perhaps building in release mode rather than debug mode, to have a product ready to ship.  You *can* do extra things, but don't *need* to.  If you want to package it up in an installer application such as an MSI then you can, which makes distributing and installing easier for end users.  Alternatively, depending on your audience, zipping it and telling users to xcopy it might be sufficient.

In terms of distribution - burning cds is out.  Use the internet.  If you're really solving a paint point for customers, and there is legit need for your app then customers will come.  How do you get traffic to your site?  Blog about it, (ideally in advance), find a few important blogs in the same vertical, with good readerships, and insert yourself into them.  Add *insightful* comments, and post a topic expanding on it in your blog, and link to it.  Build SEO, get inbound links etc.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the web as the prefered sales channel ... -1 for suggesting blogging about it `in advance` which means producing vaporware.

Comment: No - blogging about it in advance and not delivering means producing vaporware.  Doing a smoke screen is a very viable, and frequently used way, of gauging the interest in a product prior to investing significant time and resources into building it.  Also you don't need to blog about the product.  Indeed the focus should rather be on the industry, the pain, the solution, etc which establishes you as someone who knows what they're talking about, which adds credibility to your eventual tool to fix the problem.

Comment: @Filburt blogging first is a great way to determine what your minimum viable product should be.

Comment: +1 for MVP reference Graphain.  We're now really getting into startup marketing strategy and not specific software programming questions ;)

Comment: @Graphain - it's the `in advance` part I disagree with. If you already identified a problem, developed an idea and an (pre)alpha version which solves this problem it's fine to promote your product-to-be. SourceForge (forgive my reference to open source) is full projects stalling in "planning" status but raise false hopes in people searching the web for a solution. My thinking is along the lines of Joels "Always have your product ready for shipping".

Answer (score 0):

If you application is running fine then you shouldn't need to add anymore code. Now, you might want to create an installer package. This is preferable to just have the plain executable as it will aid in creating Start menu shortcuts and so forth. However, if your app is very simple, you may just want an exe; it really depends but people usually create an installer. You can create a simple one within Visual Studio.

As far as selling, there are some other things like building a web site and using some sort of payment vendor. A lot depends on your specific needs and goals.